# Terminal Freezing after Bash Script Succeeded

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2

I have a pretty simple bash script that coordinates running a couple python scripts. What I am having trouble figuring out is why after running the bash script (`. bash_script.sh`), the terminal hangs. I can't `ctrl`+`c`, `ctrl`+`z` or do anything except restart the SSH session. All I see is just a blinking cursor. Checking all the log files indicates a 0 status exit code with no errors in the scripts themselves. Running `ps aux | grep bash_script.sh` does not show any anything running either. Is there anyway to debug this?

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >> <DIR>/logfile.log 2>&1

script_message () {
    status_arg=$1

    if [[ $status_arg = "pass" ]]; then
        printf "Script Done\n"
        printf '=%.0s' {1..50}
        printf "\n"
    elif [[ $status_arg = "fail" ]]; then
        printf "Script Failed\n"
        printf '=%.0s' {1..50}
        printf "\n"
    else
        :
    fi
}

current_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day=$(date +%u)
hour=$(date +%H)

printf "RUN DATE: $current_date\n"

# activate virtual env
source /<VENV DIR/bin/activate>

python <PYTHON SCRIPT>.py >> <DIR>/logfile2.log 2>&1
retVal=$?

if [[ $retVal -eq 0 && $day -eq 4 ]]; then
    python <PYTHON SCRIPT 2>.py >> <DIR>/logfile3.log 2>&1
    script_message pass

elif [[ $retVal -eq 0 ]]; then
    script_message pass
else
    #:
    script_message fail
fi

echo $?
```

Comment: `. script` sources the script, not executes. that `exec` redirection is happening in your current shell when you source.

Comment: but why would ```exec``` redirection cause the entire terminal to hang? It should just redirect stdout and complete when the script is done running?

Comment: the terminal isn't 'hanging' ... everything you type, and all the resulting output, is being written to `logfile.log`; start 2x ssh sessions/terminals ... in 1st session `touch logfile.log; tail -f logfile.log` ... in 2nd session `exec >> logfile.log 2>&1` and then enter `date; ls; echo 'hi'` (pay attention to output displayed in 1st session as you *slowly* type commands into 2nd session; you should see your typing show up in the 1st session output ... you've basically transferred all of the 2nd session output (including the echo of your key strokes) to `logfile.log`)